# Split request - Send to either one or diff end points - combine the response

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel

I am using spring boot 2 and apache camel 2.24 to build an api gateway which exposes REST end points to receive JSON/XML request and do the following

- Validate incoming JSON/XML
- Convert incoming request to downstream expected format.
- Push the request to a camel route which invokes the downstream REST end point and returns back the response.
- Convert response to expected format and return back to client.

Currently I have route configured as below

*from("direct::camel").process(preprocessor).process(httpClientProcessor).process(postprocessor);*

httpClientProcessor - This does the main job of invoking downstream end point and return the response.

preprocessor - splits the request for configured requests, puts them in a list before passing to httpClientProcessor.

postprocessor - does the following based on content type

- XML - Remove "xml" tag from individual responses and combine to form one single response under one root element
- JSON - Combine json response under one parent array element.

There can be cases where the multiple requests need to be sent to the same end point or each to be sent to a unique end point. Currently I have that logic in httpClientProcessor. One issue with this approach is that I can invoke the downstream end points only one after another rather than in parallel (unless I add thread pool executor in httpClientProcessor)

I am new to apache camel and hence started with this basis route configuration. Based on going through the documentation, I came across camel components like split(), parallelProcessing(), multicast and aggregator components of camel but I am not sure how to plug these all together to achieve my requirement -

- Split the incoming request using a pre configured delimiter to create multiple requests. The incoming request may or may not have multiple requests.
- Based on endpoint url configuration, either post all split requests to same end point or each request to a unique endpoint.
- Combine responses from all to form one master response (XML or JSON) as output from the route.

Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you should have a look a the [Camel Split EIP](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/split-eip.html).

Especially

- How to [split a request into parts and re-aggregate the parts later](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/split-eip.html#_split_aggregate_requestreply_sample)
- How to [process each part in parallel](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/split-eip.html#_parallel_execution_of_distinct_parts)

For the dynamic downstream endpoints, you can use a dynamic To (`.toD(...)`) or the [Recipient List EIP](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/recipientList-eip.html). The latter can even send a message to multiple or no endpoint.